# CMake file(COPY), cannot set modification time

Tags: file, time, cmake, copy

I allow each target to copy all its .exe, .a, .dll, etc... files to a destination folder after the build is complete as such:

```
function(BuildMirror TARGET DESTINATION)
    # Check if folder exists
    if (NOT EXISTS "${DESTINATION}")
        message(WARNING "Destination folder did not exist, created: ${DESTINATION}")
        file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${DESTINATION}")
    endif()

    # Copy output
    add_custom_command(
            TARGET ${TARGET}
            POST_BUILD
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DDESTINATION="${DESTINATION}" -P "${BUILDCHAIN_CMAKE}/PostBuildMerge.cmake"
    )
endfunction(BuildMirror)
```

Where the PostBuildMerge.cmake is defined as such:

```
# Search
file(GLOB FILES
        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/*.a"
        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/*.dll"
        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/*.lib"
        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/*.exe"
        )

# Copy
file(COPY ${FILES} DESTINATION "${DESTINATION}")
```

Which seems to work just fine for most projects, however (I can't seem to find out why) one project fails to fully complete the copy (The file is copied) with the following message:

```
file COPY cannot set modification time on
  "xxx/Lib/Vulkan/libVkLayer_parameter_validation.dll"
```

As far as I can see CMake does not require any special permissions, and the files are not set in any read only state.

What could cause this error, and if I cant prevent it is there a way to suppress this error and continue the build since the file is copied anyway (Without a correct modification time, but that's ok).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I accidentally called BuildMirror twice in parallel, so I can only assume that it failed because the 2nd BuildMirror was overriding or something similar.

Sorry for the confusion.